# Как получить значение атрибута связаной модели, при отсутствии записи в бд yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord, relation

например:

```
Class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function getProfile()
    {

        return this->owner->hasOne(Profile::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);

    }

}


Class Profile extends\yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function rules() 
    {

        return ['name', string];

    }
    ...
}
```

Если записи в таблице profile с соответствующим user_id нет, то $user->profile вернет Null. Но в предствлении есть вывод: $user->profile->name, что в следствии выбрасывает исключение. Каким образом этого избежать, чтоб при отсутсвии записи в таблице, метод getProfile  создавал пустой экзепляр Profile. Или есть другой способ это реализовать "без костылей"

Comment: $name = !is_null($user->profile) ? $user->profile->name : '';

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Так и сделал. Только проверку сделал в геттерах, что можно было выводить DetailView.
В моделе user:
public function getProfileName(){
  return $this->profile !== Null?$this->profile->name:'';
}

Answer (score 2):

Сделал так:

```
Class User extends ActiveRecords{

   ...

   public function getProfileName()
   { 
      return !is_null($this->profile)?$this->profile->name:''; 
   } 

}
```

Если свойств много, можно вынести их в поведение, чтоб не захламлять модель